# How can I get my jquery/js code to wait for a get before continuing?

Tags: jquery, get, wait

I have a form validation method that's called on submit. It executes a "get" to validate one of the fields, and returns false if the field is invalid:

```
$.get('validate.cfc', 
    {
        method: 'validateUserID',
        userID: $('#userID').val(),
        returnformat: 'plain'
    },
    function(data){
        if($.trim(data) == 0){
            alert('Invalid userID!');
            return false;
        }
    }
);
```

It then goes on to do a few further simple validation steps (without an ajax call). For example:

```
if(!isDate($('#endDate').val()) && $('#endDate').val() != ""){
    alert("Please enter a valid end date");
    return false;
}
```

The problem is that the code continues while the `get` executes. So if the userID is not valid and the end date is not a date, first the "Please enter a valid end date" message shows up, and then the "Invalid userID!" message. How can I get my code to wait till the get is finished?

(The only thing I can think of is to put a small setTimeOut around all the rest of the code in the function after the get... not the most elegant solution.)

Comment: I did something like that  using beforeSend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right, then this should do it:

```
$.get('validate.cfc', 
{
    method: 'validateUserID',
    userID: $('#userID').val(),
    returnformat: 'plain'
},
function(data){
    if($.trim(data) == 0){
        alert('Invalid userID!');
        return false;
    }else{
            if(!isDate($('#endDate').val()) && $('#endDate').val() != ""){
            alert("Please enter a valid end date");
            return false;

            }else{
                   submit the form
                 }
         }
 }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the second part of code in the success function.

Comment: I guess that makes the most sense... I wanted to keep all the pieces of validation separate, though.

Answer (score 0):

There is an async property to send as part of your jquery ajax request, just set it to false.

Although they say in new versions it is deprecated, I have used it before and it worked.  Not sure what the new syntax is. . . or if it is

see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/